# Transfering Lion preinstalled license to new owner

Tags: macos, license

My MacBook came with Lion preinstalled, now I am selling the machine and I've read that it is possible to transfer the OS license once if the OS came preinstalled on the computer. Is there something specific that I need to do or will the license transfer complete when the new user logs in with their Apple ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing needs to be done since the Mac's serial number is used to re-download Lion so no Apple ID is tied to that installation package for the OS.

This differs from purchasing a Lion upgrade from the App Store - that isn't intended to be sold, so you'd have to adjust the sale price or gift them a card if the deal was for them to get other software included with the sale.

I've seen people trip up over iLife since it does get tied to an Apple ID rather than tied to the CPU when selling a used Mac, so *caveat venditor* and *caveat emptor* is in order.

Comment: Very good. I imagine that if the buyer will then sell the Mac in the future there still won't be problems with the Lion license right?

Comment: No - Apple can't even tell it's you downloading the OS as the first buyer, can they?